# ES6 Object Mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I was working on something but stuck at a point where I have inputs as -

```js
var definition = [
{
    "name": "objA",
    "type": "object",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "",
        "name": "A"
      },
      {
        "value": "",
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "value": "",
        "name": "C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "objX",
    "type": "object",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "",
        "name": "X"
      },
      {
        "value": "",
        "name": "Y"
      },
      {
        "value": "",
        "name": "Z"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var data = {
    "objA": {
        "A": "ValA",
        "B": "ValB",
        "C": "ValC"
    },
    "objX": {
        "X": "ValX",
        "Y": "ValY",
        "Z": "ValZ"
    }
};

const updateSchema = (data, definition) => {
        definition.forEach((subDef) => {
            var node = data[subDef.name];
            subDef.items.forEach((sub)=> {
                sub.value = node[sub.name] 
            });
        });
           
        return definition;
}

console.log(updateSchema(data,definition))
```

The output I need is

```
[
  {
    "name": "objA",
    "type": "object",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "valA",
        "name": "A"
      },
      {
        "value": "valB",
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "value": "valC",
        "name": "C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "objX",
    "type": "object",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "valX",
        "name": "X"
      },
      {
        "value": "valY",
        "name": "Y"
      },
      {
        "value": "valZ",
        "name": "Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But it gives the output as -

```
[
  {
    "name": "objA",
    "type": "object",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "ValX",
        "name": "A"
      },
      {
        "value": "ValY",
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "value": "ValY",
        "name": "C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "objX",
    "type": "object",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "ValX",
        "name": "X"
      },
      {
        "value": "ValY",
        "name": "Y"
      },
      {
        "value": "ValZ",
        "name": "Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am not able to know where I am doing wrong.

I am using React with typescript. I need to perform the above operation based on some API response.
I am prepopulating some value in the form based on the API response.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You should specify properly in the question what is data and what is definition?

Comment: @user2131395 , your code is working fine . Please run , I edited the question !

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi The value in items array is different, expected is "valX", but is "ValX".

Comment: @Jesper1 , did you run the code snippet in the question ?

Comment: ""items": [
      {
        "value": "ValA",
        "name": "A"
      },
      {
        "value": "ValB",
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "value": "ValC",
        "name": "C"
      }
    ]" is what I get when I run it.
This is the expected output: "items": [
      {
        "value": "valA",
        "name": "A"
      },
      {
        "value": "valB",
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "value": "valC",
        "name": "C"
      }
    ]

Comment: The values you have in your data array are ```ValA```, ```ValB``` and so on.  You need to change them to lowercase ```valA```, and ```valB``` in your data array.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
subDef.items.forEach((sub)=> {
                    sub.value = node[sub.name].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + node[sub.name].slice(1);
                });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j8nwpf6m/